# Assigning value to a variable after reading from a text file in perl

Tags: perl, variables, filehandle

Iam new to perl and trying to write a code where i want to read values from a text file.

Code -

```
 my $cp_server_attrib_value = $adminDB->GetTbl('cp_server_attribute_value');

my $insert_attribs = qq[
    INSERT INTO $cp_server_attrib_value(def_id, cp_server_attribute_id, value)
    VALUES ($defId,10,"30")
];
```

the server attribute id can be chanegd in the db and so can be the value further in future, so i want to get it from a text config file instead.

**Created a file :**

```
- config.txt
```

which maybe will have the following values -

```
cp_server_attribute_id= 10;
new_value=30;
```

Please can someone help me opening the file and reading the value to use in my db query.Shall i use hash? Is there an easy way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Read in lines from file and assign to temp variables
open(FILE, $file_path) or die sprintf ("FATAL: Could not open '%s' (%s)", $file_path, $!);

my ($cp_server_attribute_id, $new_value);
foreach my $line (<FILE>) {

    # Remove all whitespace because I just spotted that in your config.txt file
    $line =~ s/\s//g;

    # If the line matches our interesting attributes, extract the integer value associated
    if ( $line =~ m/^cp_server_attribute_id=(\d+);/ ) {
         $cp_server_attribute_id = $1;
    }
    elsif ( $line =~ m/^new_value=(\d+);/ ) {
         $new_value = $1;
    }
    else {
        # Do nothing
    }
}
close(FILE) || die sprintf ("FATAL: Could not close '%s' (%s)", $file_path, $!);

# Side note: This query is not recommended best practice. You should consider bind values.
my $insert_attribs = qq[
    INSERT INTO $cp_server_attrib_value(def_id, cp_server_attribute_id, value)
    VALUES ($defId, $cp_server_attribute_id, $new_value)
];
```

Additional Suggestions:

1. Pick a more commonly format for your config file. ie. XML, YAML, JSON, instead of text file
2. Find a CPAN Module which will parse that file

Comment: Thanks for this ..what if i want to use it globally and the file contains more than 15 parameters values .There are many places where this variable will be used .Please can you also advise how to store these values in a hash and then use that hash wherever required

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. What do you mean by use it globally? Global as within the scope of a script, or global as you want the configuration to persist throughout an application instance?